# Use excel to calcluate average and stdev of time differences in a time series?

Tags: excel, time-series

EDIT1: [download file with 2 days of real data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JO27suVCeBvZ_9fjzhUYof9tq4f5CYgB8U8rR2RwCk0/edit?usp=sharing)

My home automation controller collects data from several 4-in-1 motion sensors in different rooms of my house. The sensor prioritizes motion, sending motion reports every few seconds, but also independently reports temperature, humidity, and illuminance. I am trying to determine if  the temp and humidity reports are sent frequently enough to automate control of heaters and exhaust fans.

Sensors independently report each category to the controller, which sends data to excel. Sample data below, but without motion reports that clutter up the real data.

[image: time-series data]

A pivot table generated from the raw data:

[image: pivot]

Answering the question of frequency takes me several manual steps. Sorting/filtering the dataset for temp/humidity by room, then manually adding a `time diff` column

[image: temp-humidity]

where `time diff = (<current Date-Time cell> - <prev Date-Time cell>)*24*60`. I then calculate the average and stdev of `minutes between reports` by manually selecting, in turn, each room/category subset in the time diff column; once for the average and once for the stdev.

After a few more manual steps, I end up with this desired result:

[image: final result]

**BUT** I have to do it all over every time new data is added to the table. I'm certain excel can do this automatically, but I didn't find a solution through pivots, power pivots, slicing, or queries. I'm hoping one of you excel gurus can help. Thanks!

Comment: Match() or find() and look for humidity etc

Comment: Match() returns a single value - how would that help? Similar question about find(), since I'm not needing to look for substrings of cells.

Comment: I have a top 5 solution on here somewhere- you could cannibalise that… it deals with multiple returns and the duplicate issue.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions, but I don't understand. Use what function to get multiple returns? And there are no duplicates, since each record <category, room, date-time> is unique.

Comment: Perhaps some copiable data for testing purposes would prompt more responses.

Comment: @JosWoolley My apologies! Link to data added.

Comment: Thanks, and can you just confirm that the desired results you give in your final picture are those for the data in the Excel file you shared?

Comment: Yes. The min, max, avg, stdev for humidity and temp are generated by standard pivot table. I've been manually adding the time diff values after I calculate them.

Comment: @JosWoolley To clarify: the desired results table was generated from data formatted exactly like the sample data, but the values are from different days so won't match the sample data. I don't care how you format the output - I'm just interested in the solution.

Comment: But would it not be sensible to give the expected results for the data in the downloadable file you posted?